# Function defining views data type as VARCHAR2(4000) affecting performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've created a function that returns a `VARCHAR2` variable, the variable it returns is typed as `VARCHAR2(200)` within the function itself.

I've also created a view that uses that function as a column in it.  This automatically sets the datatype of that column in the view to `VARCHAR2(4000)`.

Does this cause any performance/storage issues?

Furthermore, would it be better for me to throw in a `SUBSTR` to limit it to the proper 200 characters it should be?

Oracle 11g BTW.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the `varchar2(4000)`, as long as you know that the data is actually shorter than that.

Comment: column level functional call are "timebomb". Depends on how much calculation it does for each row record and how many number of rows returned by the result set.

Comment: @Aishu - the OP uses the function in a *view*, not in a table. There's no issue with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if using `VARCHAR2(4000)` everywhere may not cause problems if everything you do is in SQL (and it may very well not cause problems in that case), it may be a pain once you start pulling data into applications. The applications may have no choice but to allocate memory based on the maximum assumed length of strings in a column... you may use up memory very quickly that way. Not to mention GUI's that will reserve and format for 4000 characters for whatever the function returns...

To limit the size of the column in the view, the solution is what you already said: if you wrap your function within `substr()` in the `select` clause of your view, the column datatype will be set to `VARCHAR2(200)`. That seems like the right approach to me.

Comment: How costly is the `substr()` assuming I don't plan on using this view outside of the oracle environment?  Is it better to leave it as it is if that is the case?

Comment: Only you will know how expensive `substr()` is (probably negligible if it comes after a call to a PL/SQL function - which presumably is at least somewhat complicated, otherwise you would have done whatever it does in SQL). On the other hand, if it's always within the Oracle database you may not need it. VARchar means variable-length; if all characters are at most 200 characters, then that's what will be stored in the DB (there will be no wasted storage or memory); only applications that rely on the catalog, not the actual data, may be confused.