# Why type of a view column does not match corresponding function result type?

Tags: oracle, plsql, view, type-conversion, column-types

Suppose having a function `my_pkg.get_prop_of`, that returns value of type `CHAR(5)`.
Also let's declare a view `my_view` with one column `prop`, gaining its value from this function call.

```
create or replace package my_pkg AS

  subtype short_string is CHAR(5);

  function get_prop_of(pi_name char)
    return short_string;    
end;    

create or replace package body my_pkg AS

  function get_prop_of(pi_name char)
    return short_string is
  begin
    return substr(pi_name || 'abcde', 1, 5);
  end;    
end;
---

create or replace view my_view as
select 
       my_pkg.get_prop_of('x') as prop
  from dual;
```

Could you explain why data dictionary shows that column type as `VARCHAR2(4000)`, what is the purpose of such behaviour?

```
select table_name, data_Type, data_length
  from all_tab_cols
 where table_name = 'MY_VIEW';

----------------------------------------------------
 TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | DATA_LENGTH
----------------------------------------------------
   MY_VIEW  |  PROP       |  VARCHAR2 |    4000
```

Looks like the Data dictionary contains the required data to let compiler apply it at the view compilation time. But somewhy it does not go that way.

```
select object_name, package_name, data_type, data_length, in_out
  from all_arguments
 where object_name = 'GET_PROP_OF';

-----------------------------------------------------------------
  OBJECT_NAME  | PACKAGE_NAME | DATA_TYPE | DATA_LENGTH | IN_OUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  GET_PROP_OF  |    MY_PKG    |   CHAR    |      5      |  OUT     <- return type
  GET_PROP_OF  |    MY_PKG    |   CHAR    |             |  IN
```

I would like to get in a clear way a matching of column type and function result type.

It is known that hard casting like `CAST(val AS CHAR(5))` could temporarily solve the problem,
but is there a more elegant way, which also handles case of changing the function return type  without need of changing `CAST` expression everywhere in the columns, calling that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when `VIEW` is created, Oracle does not know the max value of the `function` result that is returned from the `function` but it knows the data type.

Also, The fact is --> any returned value from `function` can not contain the `data precision`.

You can still achieve what you want by controlling the data type and precision in `VIEW` query using `CAST` as following:

```
SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_VIEW AS
  2      SELECT
  3          CAST(MY_PKG.GET_PROP_OF('x') AS VARCHAR2(5)) AS PROP
  4      FROM
  5          DUAL;

View created.

SQL> DESC MY_VIEW;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PROP                                               VARCHAR2(5)

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, the question is why Oracle does not know the exact type of the result, when it is clearly specified. As it is stated in the text - CAST does not solve the problem, only hiding it. And what is worse - it creates duplication of a type declaration, and a dev, who will extend `MY_PKG.short_string` would easily miss  most of ist usages in views - and compiler is not able to help him.

Comment: Because In oracle it is not allowed to return the result with precision. You can not return `NUMBER(2)`, You can only return `NUMBER`. and the same with `VARCHAR2` and other data types.

Comment: @diziaq Then your question is a wider one about why the PL/SQL language only considers the base type for parameters and ignores precision/scale/length.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, seems to me that in PL/SQL everything is correct about precision. Try SELECT DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH FROM ALL_ARGUMENTS WHERE object_name = 'function_name', moreover at the runtime a type mismatch exception could be thrown in case of returned string length overflow. The problem I'm trying to understand is exactly as stated: why type of the view column does not match return type of the corresponding function, even though it is derivable at the compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

Because you create view using your function

[Function defining views data type as VARCHAR2(4000) affecting performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004579/function-defining-views-data-type-as-varchar24000-affecting-performance)

```
create or replace view my_view as
select 
       substr(my_pkg.get_prop_of('x'),0,5) q
  from dual;

  select table_name, data_Type, data_length
  from dba_tab_cols
 where table_name = 'MY_VIEW';



MY_VIEW VARCHAR2    5
```

Comment: It is interesting why Oracle has a special treatment for `substr(x,0,5)` and can recognize the exact return type, but cannot do the same for non-standard functions.

Comment: I think, because Oracle on default unknown your function. Substr it is his function from dictionary(docs)

Comment: Nevertheless the return type of `SUBSTR` is simply `VARCHAR2`, and Oracle manages to dynamically recognize that there is a `5` passed as an argument. It seems to me that getting a known type of a compiled function is much simplier than calculating an expected result length of `substr(x, a, b)` doing `b-a+1`.

Comment: Why? get only b

Comment: I supposed the most frugal estimation. I do not know why, but even in your example if we change `mlt` to `dual`, then in `dba_tab_cols` I see `VARCHAR2(20)`. And it looks like the type length for `substr(x,a,b)` is `4b` regardless of the `a` value. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: if  you execute create or replace view tab_temp as (select 'test' col1  from dual 
        union all 
        select 'testtets' col1  from dual); Result will be VARCHAR2(8 BYTE). It is max length from value from column. Your question about only users function

Comment: Did not really get how your last comment is related to `substr`. Anyways, usage of `substr(x,0,5)` is not much better than `CAST(x as char(5))`, because in both cases we need to mention the `5` in the type declaration and in the view definition. And I am looking for a way to avoid such duplication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201081/discussion-between-rustam-pulatov-and-diziaq).